# Image Magick, installed, loaded, error opening files php

Tags: php, iis-7, imagemagick, windows-server-2008-r2, imagick

Using php 5.3 on windows 2008 in IIS 7.

I've installed NTS image magick and add php_imagick.dll to the php extensions directory and included it in php.ini . Restarted the machine and imagick shows up in phpinfo.

On [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php)
I can run example #4 without problem.

As soon as I attempt to load a file by passing the file handler, or opening directly, it fails and gives me a 500 error. Nothing in event viewer.

Also in phpinfo, the version for imagick shows '@@package version@@' , very odd.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with apache, but the problem was the same. The only solution i find out is to downgrade image magick to 6.6.4.0 version. Old builds you can find at http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue (confirmed by running example 4 with no problems but still not being able to convert).

I solved it by adding read and execute permissions for IUSR, IUSR_BLAHBLAH, NETWORK SERVICE and IUSRS to the imagemagick directory and also c:\windows\temp (adding modify permissions to that as well)

Maybe not all those users need all that access but this is a firewalled dev box and I was desperate. Maybe I'll go back and scale it down but for now this - fixes the problem.

Also I'm using:

Windows 7 x64 / IIS 7.5
PHP 5.3.6
Image Magic 6.5.9-0
Imagick 2.3.0-rc3